# how to show bar value on the top of each bar in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chartjs to draw some bar charts, I would like to show on the top of each bar the related value, I have not seen any parameters allowing to do that in the documentation.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    onAnimationComplete: function () {    
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
            });
        })
    }
```

used following link

http://jsfiddle.net/TZq6q/304/

Answer (score -3):

set  "inGraphDataShow: true" in your code it will display all values on top of bar

Comment: @Wade I have done it. may some other property you have set is affecting inGraphDataShow property..Pls check all label properties in your code

Comment: I am not using any other properties. I tried only setting this property and it didn't work, I'm using it on a demo so there aren't any conflicting properties. It's also not even on the Chartjs documentation page, so there's that.

Comment: There's no such property, by checking the source code.